# How to fix Blender closing itself mid render?

Tags: animation, cycles-render-engine, error

My Blender 3.6 keeps closing itself after rendering approximately 300 frames of my animation.
After some online searching, the only reasoning I could find was not enough vram but I have a 3080ti with 12 gb vram and the rendering at most takes only 4.8gb. Here is a one drive link to the file. Please disregard my horrible lip sync. Its for school and it's just a tutorial for downloading a software I made.
https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ap3ai__CEZG6ja5Qf_VeKSznuLe2Iw?e=3aJWGa

Comment: Could you please upload your blend file here: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Sorry @LaserLars the file is 305 mb. When I do end up cutting out enough to make it smaller it becomes no different than the original file I downloaded from the blender marketplace. I am using the Rain rig from Blender so I am using their restaurant scene file.

Comment: how do you render the animation? (single PNGs or one video file)

Comment: @Blunder Sorry about that. Here is a working link: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ap3ai__CEZG6jcEvcDwVVdgQEovfuA?e=9XEwpq
They are rendered to single pngs using blenders internal Cycles render engine.